# Error running query from hyperledger composer Queries tutorial against couchdb Fabric runtime

Tags: hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to connect the dots between Composer and Fabric to build a proof of concept application that supports multiple orgs.  So, I am using the Composer tutorials to build the business network and then the "Deploying to a multi-organization business network" tutorial (which references the Fabric "Build your first network" tutorial, but tells you to use a different git repo than the BYFN tutorial, which I did).

I was able to use the Developer tutorial from Composer to build the simple trade business network, and then copy the archive to the folder where I built out the multi-org business network with Fabric (which requires couchdb, which I'd want to use anyway in order to be able to do more complex querying), start it all up and then use the explorer REST API to create participants, assets, and trade transactions.  This all worked fine.

Then, I moved onto the Composer Queries tutorial to add the queries.qry, generate a new archive, copied & updated the fabric install of the archive, stopped & updated & restarted the REST API server.  I can see the queries in the REST API now so I know it has picked up the new code.  However, regardless of which of the queries I try to run through the REST API explorer, they all return the same error:

```
  {
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Couch DB Error:invalid_operator,  Status Code:400,  Reason:Invalid operator: $class)",
    "stack": "Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Couch DB Error:invalid_operator,  Status Code:400,  Reason:Invalid operator: $class)\n    at channel.queryByChaincode.then.catch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:809:34)\n    at <anonymous>"
  }
}
```

The simplest of the queries from the tutorial is a simple get all with no arguments, so the problem can't be what I'm passing in (as there is literally nothing to pass in).  The problem has to be something systemic.

Example: the get all commodities query

```
query selectCommodities {
  description: "Select all commodities"
  statement:
      SELECT org.acme.biznet.Commodity
}
```

The error message says it doesn't like $class in the response.

```
The response from the GET all commodities endpoint (which doesn't use the query) is:

[
  {
    "$class": "org.acme.biznet.Commodity",
    "tradingSymbol": "KPX",
    "description": "KnitPicks",
    "mainExchange": "SP",
    "quantity": 50,
    "owner": "resource:org.acme.biznet.Trader#4567"
  },
  {
    "$class": "org.acme.biznet.Commodity",
    "tradingSymbol": "KPX2",
    "description": "KnitPicks",
    "mainExchange": "SP",
    "quantity": 120,
    "owner": "resource:org.acme.biznet.Trader#4567"
  }
]
```

and the API doc for the selectCommodities query sample response is of the same format:

```
[
  {
    "$class": "org.acme.biznet.Commodity",
    "tradingSymbol": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "mainExchange": "string",
    "quantity": 0,
    "owner": {}
  }
]
```

so I am not sure what is wrong, but it seems like it would have to be either a problem with the query itself not being compatible with CouchDB, or a problem in the translation layer from the query in Composer to the low level Fabric API?  The latter theory is supported by the 500 being returned by the Composer API layer having a nested 400 error, implying that something that the Composer layer through hlfconnection is passing is invalid.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  I can't imagine I'm the first to run across this but I haven't found anything online that's directly related.
Thanks in advance!

Composer version 0.16.6

Docker PS:

f844a2957bd5        dev-peer0.org2.example.com-tutorial-network-0.16.6-95a0f8a4fe6ff659a5943abc80b26a1134e77b74942eef102fa92c8480b680eb   "chaincode -peer.add…"   24 hours ago        Up 24 hours                                                            dev-peer0.org2.example.com-tutorial-network-0.16.6
556c9f3841ce        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.16.6-e4f751b9b8b3a307f6bf25ea97ccf3625bd75730a1dcb3f989a9a34bbb73f536   "chaincode -peer.add…"   24 hours ago        Up 24 hours                                                            dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.16.6
831ca5b9a839        dev-peer1.org2.example.com-tutorial-network-0.16.6-a184efa69bdcbcb2e6ec3764e01d56f0c574ca0ad09d4656269d3b7aefbc44b8   "chaincode -peer.add…"   24 hours ago        Up 24 hours                                                            dev-peer1.org2.example.com-tutorial-network-0.16.6
6faf5b875df9        dev-peer1.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.16.6-44b9f2a6ea1ed75f106aa0b5fc8387c95cbde9eee551df9fb36d16709f2db981   "chaincode -peer.add…"   24 hours ago        Up 24 hours                                                            dev-peer1.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.16.6
afbcbe9292fd        dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-26c2ef32838554aac4f7ad6f100aca865e87959c9a126e86d764c8d01f8346ab                  "chaincode -peer.add…"   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours                                                            dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
8444f922486d        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0-384f11f484b9302df90b453200cfb25174305fce8f53f4e94d45ee3b6cab0ce9                  "chaincode -peer.add…"   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours                                                            dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0
753588bacb47        dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-15b571b3ce849066b7ec74497da3b27e54e0df1345daff3951b94245ce09c42b                  "chaincode -peer.add…"   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours                                                            dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
662b61c00673        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                               "peer node start"        26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
80a37822a0d6        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                               "peer node start"        26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
2878eacafb29        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                               "peer node start"        26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
e8f3259dca2a        hyperledger/fabric-peer                                                                                               "peer node start"        26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
a79c29e762cd        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                                            "tini -- /docker-ent…"   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6984->5984/tcp         couchdb1
34271122957a        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                                            "tini -- /docker-ent…"   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8984->5984/tcp         couchdb3
8b88227ea7a7        hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                                 "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                             ca_peerOrg1
a75fa6328b02        hyperledger/fabric-ca                                                                                                 "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:8054->7054/tcp                             ca_peerOrg2
4e21c3c8fa16        hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                                                                            "orderer"                26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                             orderer.example.com
2881999a4c7b        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                                            "tini -- /docker-ent…"   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7984->5984/tcp         couchdb2
8a77a5e86a3a        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                                            "tini -- /docker-ent…"   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours         4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp         couchdb0

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Composer 0.17.6, peers 1.1.0, couchdb 0.4.6 Have you managed?

Comment: Can you post your composer version (`composer -v`) and `docker ps` please?

Comment: Composer version v0.16.6

Docker PS is too long for a comment apparently, so I'll add to initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to a match of Composer version (16.x) to versions of Fabric (1.1).  Composer 0.16.x ONLY works with Fabric v1.0.x (you can check from your logs / `docker images` what you installed). The release notes detail which versions of composer will work with which versions of fabric. eg
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases

```
Composer v0.18.2 and above is compatible with Fabric 1.1 GA only
Composer v0.18.0 -> v0.18.1 : compatible with the Fabric 1.1 RC1 driver only
Composer v0.17.3 -> v0.17.6 (old) are compatible with Fabric 1.1 alpha driver only

Composer v0.16.x -> compatible with Fabric v1.0.x only
```

Comment: This was the issue, I had been doing tutorials both from the Fabric site and from the Composer site so there was a mismatch in version.  Thank you for the assistance!